# What does the lower integral mean?

Tags: integration, definition, riemann-integration

> Defintion: ${}_{-}\int_a^b f(x) \,\text{d}x = \sup \{L(f,p) \mid \text{$p$ is a partition of $[a,b]$} \}$ where $L(f,p)$ is the lower sum.

My problem: I am confused with the definition itself of the lower integral as $L(f,p)$ should be a number, so how would I take the supremum of a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each partition $p$, $L(f, p)$ is a (real) number. For different partitions $p$, you get (potentially) different results for $L(f, p)$.
$$
\{L(f, p)\mid p \text{ is a partition of }[a, b]\}
$$
is the set of all those possible reults. You are supposed to take the supremum of this set of numbers.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. How would one find a partition that is the supreme?

Comment: @ViB You don't. Unless the function is (piecewise) constant, there is no "supreme" partition. The finer you make the partition, the larger the result gets. And any partition can be made finer, which means that for any lower sum there is another lower sum which is larger. However, there is a bound on how large the lower sums can get. And that bound is the lower integral. Calculating this is not always trivial, and how one would do it depends on the function.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

$L(f,p)$ is a *number*, sure, but

$$\{L(f,p)|p\text{ is a partition of }[a,b]\}$$ is a *set* of numbers, and the definition takes the supremum of this set.